# Why can't Spotlight find an application I know is there?

Tags: mac, finder, macos, spotlight

I have this application called Cura Type A, but Spotlight cannot find it, even when I show all results in Finder... Anyone know why?

[image: Cura Type A]

Comment: I have the same issue. Spotight finds most apps in the applications folder, but some it doesnt. For me it cant find Slack.  Extremely annoying, as I cant launch it via spotlight.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible that your Spotlight index is damaged or incomplete. The app does launch and function correctly, right? If so try rebuilding the Spotlight index.

Launch System Preferences, Click on Spotlight and then click the Privacy tab. Drag your HD icon into this window. Click OK when asked to confirm.

Other housekeeping utilities (like Onyx) will also rebuild the Spotlight index.

Comment: I believe you also need to _remove_ your HD from the list afterward, or Spotlight will be prevented from indexing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

If searching your Mac doesn’t return expected results, rebuilding the Spotlight index might help.

1. Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Spotlight.
   Click the Privacy tab.
2. Drag the folder or disk that you want to index again to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Or click the Add (+) button and select the folder or disk to add.

   - To add an item to the Privacy tab, you must have ownership permissions for that item. To learn about permissions, choose Help from the Finder menu bar, then search for “permissions.”
3. From the same list of locations, select the folder or disk that you just added. Then click the Remove (–) button to remove it from the list.
4. Quit System Preferences. Spotlight will reindex the contents of the folder or disk.

Answer (score 0):

Before rebuilding or anything make sure Spotlight is searching the correct directory or filetype.  Open System Preferences and click on Spotlight. The window that opens lets you define certain aspects of spotlight search.